# How to dynamically share a package-wide config variable?

Tags: python, configuration, python-module, python-packaging

I am building a python package, which has a module called "config", in which I have defined different files that contain some global variables that are used as configuration in other modules.

```
.
└── mypackage
    ├── base.py
    ├── config
    │   ├── completion.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── locals.py
    │   └── queries.py
    ├── encoders.py
    ├── exceptions.py
    ├── functions
    │   ├── actions.py
    │   ├── dummy.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── parsers.py
    │   └── seekers.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── query.py
    └── utils
        ├── dict.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── retry.py
```

For example, the file `mypackage/config/queries.py` has the following content:

```
INCLUDE_PARENTS = False
```

Whereas in the main file `mypackage/base.py`, I have a function which takes this config variable as a default argument:

```
import mypackage.config.queries as conf

def query(include_parent_=conf.INCLUDE_PARENTS, **kwargs):
    # do stuff depending on include_parent_ argument
```

What I want, and what I haven't been able to find in other similar questions, is to be able to dynamically modify these variables in a Python/Ipython console session. That is, I should be able to do the following on Ipython:

```
In [1]: import mypackage as mp

In [2]: mp.config.INCLUDE_PARENTS = True # Its default value was False

In [3]: mp.query()
Out[3]: # result with include_parent_ argument set to True

In [4]: mp.config.INCLUDE_PARENTS = False # Now I set the value back to False

In [5]: mp.query()
Out[5]: # result with include_parent_ argument set to False
```

But I don't understand why I am not able to achieve it. I have tried importing the configuration variables in **init**.py with their associated namespace, but I never manage to be able to change the global configuration variables dynamically, as Pandas does, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `conf.INCLUDE_PARENTS` as a default parameter of a function. A default parameter is evaluated when the function is created **not when it is called**. Thus, when you change your code later, the value inside the function does not change. The following should work as you expect.

```
def query(include_parent_=None, **kwargs):
    if include_parent_ is None:
        include_parent_ = conf.INCLUDE_PARENTS
    # do stuff depending on include_parent_ argument
```